# What to do with an ANOVA that tells that your GLMM is not significant compared with its nullmodel?

Tags: anova, glmm

I have made a GLMM that gave me one of the variables as significant. However, when I did an ANOVA comparing this model with its nullmodel the result was not significant. This means that my model does not fit my data very well. What can I conclude from here? Does it mean that actually, the model cannot infer anything about the data I collected? Or that there is no effect of that variable in my data?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you cannot say for sure that any variation explained by the model you created can be attributed to anything more than random chance.

That makes it a non-informative model, so inference would be non-sensical.

That having been said, you have one significant variable, you can start there and add other variables one at a time to see if you can build a more robust model. Sometimes having everything in there when some variables are chaotic, robs other variables of their predictive capabilities. But I would have tempered expectation. You may find that you need to seek out new data sources if you need to build a meaningful model!